# How to find the largest number in a set of random numbers

Tags: java

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Type a number");
int n = s.nextInt();
int start = 0;
int largest = 0;
int occurrence = 0;

while(n > start){
    int number = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    if(number > largest){
        largest = number;


    }
    n--;
    System.out.print(number+" ");
}

System.out.println("max is "+largest);
System.out.println("Occurrence is "+occurrence);
```

I would like to be able to find the occurrence of the largest int, and I am not sure how to go about doing so, in a rather simple way. I tried adding `occurrence++;` under `largest = number;`, but that did not work.

For example, I would type `6` as input, and I would get random numbers `54, 74, 61, 89, 13, 89`. 
The desired output would be `max is 89. Occurrence is 2.`

Also, I am trying to only get the code to print only 10 numbers per line, then it would skip to the next line and continue.

Answer (score 1):

1. In case of reoccurrence, increase occurrence variable;
2. set occurrence to `1` in case of new larger number

You can use

```
if(number > largest){
    largest = number; // found larger value
    occurrence = 1; // reset occurrence back to initial 
}else if(number == largest){
     occurrence++; // keep track of same large value
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be `occurrence = 1` in the if condition `( number > largest )`.

Comment: @SomeDude yeah thanks, actually i was going to advice to display the occurrence variable with plus one , though will be little confusing , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `else if` condition to check equality like this

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a number");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int start = 0;
    int largest = 0;
    int occurrence = 1;

    while(n > start){
        int number = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        if(number > largest){
            largest = number;


        }else if(number == largest){
            occurrence++;
        }
        n--;
        System.out.print(number+" ");
    }

    System.out.println("max is "+largest);
    System.out.println("Occurrence is "+occurrence);
```

**P.S** - Initialize `occurrence  = 1` as there will be at least one time the largest number will be present

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there. Basically, you are missing a check on whether the new random number is equal to the current largest number. Something like:

```
if (number == largest) {
    occurrences++;
}
```

Also, remember to reset occurrences when a new largest number has been found:

```
if (number > largest){
    largest = number;
    occurrences = 1;
}
```